# Take pictures using iPad's camera with Selenium and Appium

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I am automating `iOS` application in iPad using `Selenium` and `Appium`.
The application has one feature where it opens iPad's default camera application and user can take picture from it.
The requirement is to automate this procedure. i.e. Capture picture using iPad's default camera and use it in application.
Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't directly take pictures from your iPad with Selenium/Appium, but there is a tool named AVFoundation that allows you to do so.

There is some documentation about [taking pictures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)

The programming language that is used is Objective-C.

Hope you'll find what you are looking for.